# Strawberry Perl cannot install Mason templates

Tags: windows, perl, mason

Hi cannot install mason templates on Strawberry Perl on windows 10 x64.
I've installed strawberry-perl-5.24.1.1-64bit.msi
CPAN works normally.

Any help would be great.

Guard installation fails:

```
C:\Strawberry\Echo>cpanm Mason
--> Working on Mason
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/J/JS/JSWARTZ/Mason-2.24.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Mason-2.24 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Guard
--> Working on Guard
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/Guard-1.023.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Guard-1.023 ... OK
Building and testing Guard-1.023 ... FAIL
! Installing Guard failed. See C:\Users\DRASKO~1.POP\.cpanm\work\1485557949.7836\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Guard' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Mason-2.24.

C:\Strawberry\Echo>cpanm  --verbose Guard
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7042 on perl 5.024001 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
Work directory is C:\Users\DRASKO~1.POP/.cpanm/work/1485557107.8988
You have make C:\Strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe
You have LWP 6.15
Falling back to Archive::Tar 2.24
You have C:\FPC\3.0.0\bin\i386-Win32\unzip.exe
Searching Guard () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Guard
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/Guard-1.023.tar.gz ... OK
Unpacking Guard-1.023.tar.gz
Entering Guard-1.023
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.24)
Running Makefile.PL
Configuring Guard-1.023 ... Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Guard
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.24)
Building and testing Guard-1.023 ... cp Guard.pm blib\lib\Guard.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Guard ()
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 "Guard.bs"
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- Guard.bs blib\arch\auto\Guard\Guard.bs 644
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp"  -typemap C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap  Guard.xs > Guard.xsc
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- Guard.xsc Guard.c
gcc -c          -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2      -DVERSION=\"1.023\"   -DXS_VERSION=\"1.023\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   Guard.c
In file included from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:689: sys\types.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:707: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:718: ctype.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:729: locale.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:764: setjmp.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:785: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:923: stddef.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:936: string.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1084: sys\stat.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1113: time.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1134: errno.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1789: limits.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1792: float.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1811: limits.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1814: float.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:1843: limits.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:2434: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:2684,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\handy.h:77: stdbool.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:2795,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\dosish.h:110: signal.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32thread.h:4,
                 from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:3159,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:131: windows.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:159: io.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:160: process.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:161: stdio.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:162: direct.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:163: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:164: stddef.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:165: fcntl.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:426,
                 from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32thread.h:4,
                 from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:3159,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\sys\socket.h:13: windows.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\sys\socket.h:21: winsock2.h: No such file or directory
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\sys\socket.h:30: ws2tcpip.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\sys\socket.h:184,
                 from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32.h:426,
                 from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32thread.h:4,
                 from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:3159,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\sys\errno2.h:10: winsock2.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:3648: assert.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\iperlsys.h:51,
                 from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:3856,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perlio.h:41: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:3856,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\iperlsys.h:920: setjmp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:4449: math.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:5576,
                 from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\win32iop.h:16: sys\utime.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Guard.xs:4:
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\perl.h:6526: fcntl.h: No such file or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Guard.o'
FAIL
! Installing Guard failed. See C:\Users\DRASKO~1.POP\.cpanm\work\1
```

485557107.8988\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.

Comment: Looks similar to [this issue](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.win32.vanilla/2011/06/msg312.html). gcc isn't finding any of the standard header files.

Comment: [Check to see if you have another `gcc` installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line#304447) and if Strawberry is using that.

Comment: Thanks guys. I followed @ThisSuitIsBlackNot advice and it was the same issue. I had Free pascal installed and it was in path prior to strawberry. I assume Free pascal is using gcc too.

Comment: Great! Feel free to write up your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed the path order for Strawberry in Edit environment variable. As noted in this [thread](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.win32.vanilla/2011/06/msg315.html)
[image: Screenshot from path]