# where is ipy.exe in Windows 10?

Tags: python, window, windows-10, ironpython, renderdoc

I have access to IronPython interactive shell but I don't know where it is installed. Searching for it in the directories yields no result and it is not recognized by cygwin or command prompt as it is not in the path.
[image]

I am running renderdocui.exe as administrator in this folder however there is no ipy.exe here or elsewhere in my machine, hence I am confused how does it find ipy.exe for the interactive shell within RenderDoc UI itself.
[image]

*As I said, ipy is not recognized, so solutions like this won't work:

```
C:\Users\mona\Downloads\whereis\mvp_tips\whereis\Debug>whereis.exe ipy.exe
The specified module could not be found.


C:\Users\mona\Downloads\whereis\mvp_tips\whereis\Debug>whereis.exe python
C:\Python27\python.exe
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\python.exe
       (Default) => "C:\Python27\Python.exe"
```

Also as for PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\mona> which python
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\python.exe
C:\Users\mona\Anaconda3\python.exe
PS C:\Users\mona> which ipy
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
PS C:\Users\mona> which ipy.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

**The error stems from running this bash script:

```
mona@DESKTOP-37GGNHL /cygdrive/c/Users/mona/playing-for-data/renderdoc/renderdocui/ironpython
$ ./compilelibs.sh .
./compilelibs.sh: line 13: ./ipy.exe: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: @Marat please see the update to the question

Comment: isn't it called ipython.exe on Windows?

Comment: I am running an executable from renderdoc author and it is called ipy.exe

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question. I was thinking you're trying to find system IPython, and thus my comments are irrelevant

Comment: IPython is exactly the IPython interpreter. If run without parameters (*.py filename) it will open a shell