# which pip.exe is used when I type the pip command on console

Tags: python, pip

I have several pip.exe, one in python package,another in anaconda. when i input pip in windows console,which pip.exe will be used,and why the pip.exe is used.

Comment: Read about the PATH environment variable...

Comment: @Luke Park  neither directory of the two pip.exe was added to PATH environment variable,however,pip command  works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type `where pip` from windows command line. You will get to know which pip.exe is being used

```
C:\Users\lade>where pip
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe

C:\Users\lade>
```

For more details on where [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)