# 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows 7

Tags: windows

I am trying to run "which" command in windows 7 in command prompt, but again and again not recognized output coming, I have added the system32 path in environment variable also, but still getting the same output.

is there any other way to add "which" command in windows7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: The `which` program is not shipped with the Windows OS; I think it is less useful in a GUI environment.

Comment: i tried to add like telnet command , but it was not there .

Answer (score 0):

Can be done. Have to install+configure cygwin/cygwin64 or unix utils, 
look for ( after installation ) which.exe and set path to that folder.
then you'll be able to execute it.