# how to create a separate python 2.7 environment in conda?

Tags: python

I am using anaconda and python 3.8. Now some of my codes need to be run with python 2. so I create a separate python 2.7 environment in conda  like below:

after that, I installed spyder, then launcher spyder amd spyder is showing I am still using python 3.8

how do i do to use python 2.7 in spyder with a new environment?

Thanks

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 ipykernel
conda activate py27
pip install spyder
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/switch-environment/), this should create a python2.7 virtual environment (29 April 2021) with spyder installed. I verified that spyder version 3.3.6 is python2.7 compatible

```
conda create -y -n py27 python=2.7 spyder=3.3.6
```

However, I could not run `spyder` in the `py27` environment due to conflicts that `conda` failed to catch. The workaround shown by [asanganuwan](https://github.com/asanganuwan) on  this [Spyder Github Issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13510#issuecomment-754392635) page worked for me also

> Found a workaround to use Spyder on python 2.7.
>
> ```
> setup two virtual environments for Python 2.7 and 3.6.
> Launce anaconda navigator and install spyder 3.3.6 on both the environments
> Launch spyder on the environment with Python 3.6
> Preferences-->Python Interpreter --> set the Python path for 2.7
> Restart Spyder
> Done!
> ```

So my recommendation is next run

```
conda create -y -n py36 python=3.6 spyder=3.3.6
conda activate py36
spyder
```

And follow the last three instructions from asanganuwan.

Also you should use the `conda` package manager as much as possible since it is smarter with managing requirements. When I try to use `pip install spyder` after activating the environment, it warns of version conflicts and fails to start.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to first search for an anaconda 2.7 version you want, then install it explicitly, this will make resolving much faster, give you a "stable" anaconda and allow you more control while installing all anaconda packages:
First:

```
conda search anaconda
```

Then select a version that has 27, in my case:

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
anaconda                      custom          py27_0  pkgs/main
anaconda                      custom          py27_1  pkgs/main
anaconda                      custom  py27h689e5c3_0  pkgs/main
anaconda                      custom          py35_1  pkgs/main
............
anaconda                       5.3.1          py27_0  pkgs/main
anaconda                       5.3.1          py37_0  pkgs/main
............
anaconda                     2019.10          py27_0  pkgs/main
............
```

I went with:

```
conda create -n py2 Python=2.7 anaconda==5.3.1 -y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage environments from Ananconda's Navigator. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/getting-started/#navigator-managing-environments

Answer (score 0):

**I guess you are on previous pip;**

1. Use `which pip` command to find out your current pip environment.
2. Modify your **.bash** file and set another new environment variable for your new pip.
3. Source your **.bash** file.
4. Try to install **spyder** by using new pip env variable; something like `pipX install spyder`

Comment: thanks DRPK, I am using win10. which is not recognized as an internal or external command. Thanks for your help

Comment: @roudan: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: @roudan; open your environment variables from start menu; then make new variable for your new pip; but set different name for it, not same as your global pip.

Comment: (py27) C:\Users\yongn>where.exe pip
C:\Users\yongn\miniconda3\Scripts\pip.exe  after that, how do i make new variable for which pip?

Comment: how to modify bash file, sorry I am not familiar with it at all.

Comment: @roudan; the methods i wrote for you are in linux/unix platforms...iam searching for their equivalents or alternatives for windows and reading somethings about conda

Comment: @roudan; did you cd in your new environment ?

Comment: @roudan; after conda activate py27; did you cd in your path ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227716/discussion-between-drpk-and-roudan).