How to install pip for python 2.7 on ubuntu 23.10
There are some links such as here for instructions on how to install pip2 on ubuntu with python 2.7, however when I run
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2.7 ~/get-pip.py

I get this error:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
How do I install pip on for python 2.7 on ubuntu?

Why do you want to install pip2? Why do you want to work with python 2.7? That's been sunset and the world has moved to python 3

What is your Python version? python2.7 --version ? How have you installed it? From deadsnakes? Compiled from sources? Do you have modules ssl and _ssl? python2.7 -c "import _ssl" ?

apt-get install python-pip will install Pip for Python 2.7 on Debian-like platforms, still. You might not be able to do much with it, though. (On some versions it will be in /usr/bin/pip2.)

@tripleee https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=mantic&searchon=names&keywords=python-pip "Sorry, your search gave no results". On modern Debian-like platforms Python 2.7 is no longer distributed. They only distribute Python 3, currently 3.11.

Consider using conda. Install miniconda or miniforge, For miniconda set conda config --add channels conda-forge, create an environment: conda create -n py27 python=2.7 and activate it: conda activate py27 . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856151/how-to-create-a-separate-python-2-7-environment-in-conda , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=conda+python-2.7

@phd My bad, you'll have to pick it up from the 2304 packages (Jammy)

I need it to replicate a package written in python 2.7. My version is python 2.7.9 and I installed it through
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-2.7.9.tgz
cd Python-2.7.9
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
I am a bit confused by your last comment @tripleee

What I tried to say is that if you have Ubuntu 23.10 or newer, you will need to rig your Apt configuration to get the python-pip package from the old 23.04 packages.

@JoeEmmens When compiling from sources you need to make sure you have older OpenSSL and its headers (from development package); older Python requires old OpenSSL. After compilation check that _ssl was compiled. Python 2.7.9 requires OpenSSL 0.8.7 or may be 1.0.1. For 1.1.1 try Python 2.7.15. See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html
