# How to Determine the path of the "curl" command from the command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, curl, command-prompt

I just wanted to know if there was a way to find the path of the "curl" command on my computer. I open up the command prompt and I can execute the curl command no problem. But I have to wonder how does the command prompt know what the curl command is. I assume it is pointing to some executable somewhere. Is there a way to trace the location of the executable using the command prompt itself?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows you can use the `where` command to locate programs

```
where curl.exe
```

On my machine it answers:

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
```

Comment: Very simple answer thankyou! I was looking at my system environment variables but it doesn't specify each command and their location. But this is useful to know!

Comment: [Here is the explanation](https://curl.se/windows/microsoft.html) of why cURL is located in System32.