Running Go application from Powershell gives output from unrelated project
I've recently started experimenting with Go.  I wrote the following code in VS Code on Windows 11.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("This now works.")
}

This runs fine from within VS Code. When I run the program from the Powershell using the go run command it also produces the appropriate output.
C:\Users\stuff\Documents\code\go\trial> go run main.go
This now works.

However, when I use 'go build' to build the exe and then run executable it gives me this:
C:\Users\stuff\Documents\code\go\trial> go build main.go
C:\Users\stuff\Documents\code\go\trial> main.exe
153
10.1
Hello world.
true

This output is from a previous Go project I was working on just practicing passing values back and forth with functions. I deleted the old project and folder where it was saved prior even initializing my current module. Is Powershell referencing some temp build somewhere? How can I prevent this?
Thank you.

go build creates a binary in your current directory, e.g. ./main.exe. Without a qualifying path, you are executing another main.exe from somewhere else in your PATH. (also don't use filename arguments to the go command, see How to Write Go Code to get started)

Thank you.  I'm still trying to find out where this other version of the main.exe is because I deleted folder it was in.  I'll check the folders on the PATH.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line may help

run Get-Command main or gc main and you'll get which main.exe actually executed. PowerShell doesn't search PATH first for executables, just like *nix shells, so you must use .\main.exe if you want to run the one in the current directory

Thank you for the follow up.  I think I've got it worked out now.  I appreciate the clarification.
