# Why doesn't the 'where' command display any output when running in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

When I run `where` in CMD, I get output:

```
C:\Users\Ragesh> where calc
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
```

But the same thing in PS:

```
PS C:\data\code> where calc
PS C:\data\code>
```

Where's the output going?!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
PS C:\Users\Bill> where.exe calc
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
```

When you type `where` in PS, it is not same as executing `where.exe`

```
PS C:\Users\Bill> where  <press ENTER>

cmdlet Where-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Property:
```

So when you type `where calc` it is executing `Where-Object calc` (the alias of `Where-Object` is `where` and `?`) and thus returns nothing, and not executing `where.exe calc`.

You can use the `Get-Command` (alias `gcm`) cmdlet instead of `where.exe`. Here is an example function to make `Get-Command` function exactly like `where.exe`. If you put this in your [PowerShell profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/04/understanding-and-using-powershell-profiles.aspx) it will always be available in your session.

```
function which ($command) {
    Get-Command -Name $command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

The following links may be useful -

[Equivalent of *Nix 'which' command in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell)

https://superuser.com/questions/34492/powershell-equivalent-to-unix-which-command

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It doesn't explain why 'where' doesn't show any output in PS, though.

Comment: @Ragesh I updated the answer with explanation and a way to get this to work. Pls let me know if u have questions.

Comment: You can also run it in using cmd.exe. Like `cmd /c "where calc"`

Comment: @Graimer Absolutely ...pls free to edit the answer if you want.

Comment: You can see the command precedence that leads to this by issuing `get-command where -CommandType all`.

Comment: is there any way of switching off this behaviour?  I found the same problem with 'sc' (for mucking around with services) and then tried to 'where' sc.  Thought my computer had gone crazy!  I dont want to use cmd because of the obvious horribleness but powershell randomly replacing stuff with other stuff is also awful

Answer (score 1):

@Bill's answer is one reason.

Another is you're in the Powershell ISE in which case `where.exe` invokes a new command shell that opens, prints the output, and closes immediately.