# How can I test if Notepad++ is installed via powershell?

Tags: powershell, notepad++

I would like to test if notepad++ is installd via powershell and if installed, I will open a text file with notepad++ otherwise with notepad.

```
$textfile = "d:\fooBar.txt)"
if (<# notepad++ installed?#>
{
 notepad++ $textfile
}
notepad $textfile
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [this post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software/) which I used to come up with the below.

```
# Get the Notepad++ registry item, if it exists (32bit)
$np = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq 'Notepad++'} |
Select-Object DisplayName,DisplayIcon

if($np -ne $null){
    # Launch based on DisplayIcon being notepad++.exe
    # You could manipulate this string or another registry entry for added robustness.
    & $np.DisplayIcon $textfile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Equivalent of *Nix 'which' command in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell)

This should help you. In UNIX, the *which* command shows you where a program is installed. 
From there, you can check if returned string is empty or not.
Good luck :)

Comment: I am not sure this is what OP is looking for. Get-Command finds notepad.exe because it exists in a path in the environment variable %PATH%. This won't work for Notepad++.exe because is not (by default) installed in any path within the %PATH% env var.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume default paths you can just check for the .exe.

```
if ( $ENV:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq 'AMD64' ){
    $npp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
} else {
    $npp = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
}

if ($npp){
    &$npp 'c:\folder\document.txt'
}
```

Comment: Using `$env:ProgramFiles` would be better than guessing the folder name.