# python failed to run

Tags: python, powershell, terminal, command-prompt

I am having a problem with my python.It is showing python failed to run error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZI7z.png)

I tried to run simple python program in vscode, it is showing the error('python failed to run').when i entered the command(python --version) in command prompt ,it is showing python version, but it is throwing error in terminal.I tried to run my c++ files in vscode,they are working absolutely fine.my python version is python 3.11.4. so can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:powershell]? What happens when you use the [tag:command-Prompt] (`cmd`)?

Comment: Duplicate? [Python and Powershell issue even after adding it to path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58912217/1701026)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: after installing python (assuming you did that) and checking the option to add it to your path, you need to start a new shell to get the updated environment.

Answer (score 2):

Add path of `python` (or python interpreter) in your environment variables, to run python on command line or shell.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `python.exe` is not in your environment variables. Hence, PowerShell fails to locate your Python interpreter. You can address this problem by opening the configuration panel (type `env` in the Windows searchbar) then clicking, under `Advanced System Settings`, the `Environment Variables...` button. Then create a variable named `python` and assign the **absolute path** to your Python interpreter (the aforementioned `python.exe`) to it.