# PowerShell The term 'which' is not recognized as cmdlet function script file or operable program

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell and want to do a `which` command, however I am seeing this error:

```
which : The term 'which' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ which xxxxxx
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (which:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have done a search on Google and there is no specific answer to my question. Has anyone encountered the same error before and how can I fix it?

Comment: the word `which` is NOT a powershell command. why do you think it is such?

Comment: [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) is a standard command of Linux, but is not normally present on Windows. You may be looking for `Get-Command` or `where.exe`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks Jeroen. `Get-Command` works for my use! Appreciated the help!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Hi Lee - Thanks for pointing it out. I am following an instruction online and it is using `which`. I am rookie to PowerShell and have no idea which command I should use.. :(

Comment: Probably I should have checked for existing questions first: [Equivalent of \*Nix 'which' command in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting an answer together from the comments:

[`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) is a standard command of Linux, but is not normally present on Windows.

The equivalent command is `Get-Command`, or if you have it, you can run `where.exe`.