# What is the equivalent to the bash/shell/UNIX-terminal command 'which' in Windows 10 PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, shell, executable

How do I check where an executable of a program is located using `PowerShell`?

In the `bash` shell it'd be (e.g. for Python):

```
$ which python
/c/Users/user/.pyenv/pyenv-win/shims/python
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the additional resources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of \*Nix 'which' command in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell)

Comment: That's the same link @Daniel posted already. Several answers and rationales are provided, but I like the conciseness of Martin's answer below. Nothing else is needed for my scope, it just works.

Comment: Yes, it is, but they hadn't actually voted for duplicate closure. The `gcm` answers is also on the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63891/3001761. You might not need the other options, but the point of this process is for the _next person_ who finds this who might.

Comment: I agree. The only thing that got me was the naming of that duplicate question, wherefore I couldn't find it myself. While it might be more accurate to say `*NIX` it might not be obvious for everyone, especially for those not being experts in the field. If I can't find a question with various search trials, I file my own and then of course one can link to the other one which is more popular. Yet, I feel stackoverflow should allow for more search criteria linking questions to other keywords, even though these might not be mentioned directly in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=AZ-5003203) cmdlet (short `gcm`) for that:

```
gcm python
```